# While installing on OSX Sierra via gcc-6, keep having "FATAL:/opt/local/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!" error

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, xgboost

### Environment info

Operating System:
macOS 10.12.2 (16C68)

Compiler:
gcc-6

### Steps to reproduce

I've installed gcc-6 and modified config.mk as required into

`export CC = gcc-6
export CXX = g++-6`

But keep having this error:

`g++-6 -c -std=c++0x -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp src/learner.cc -o build/learner.o
FATAL:/opt/local/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!`

### What have you tried?

1. Reinstall `XCode`
2. Reinstall `gcc`
3. Run `make clean_all && make -4j`

But still went wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue when using `macports`-installed gnu assembler. You could try forcing the use of `as` that comes with Xcode, or simply temporarily removing `/opt/local/bin` from your path.

Comment: Amazing I have exact the same issue after having updating to Big Sur, this solved thanks

Answer (score 2):

I solved by uninstalling MacPorts:

```
sudo port -f uninstall installed
```