# Gcc not working on MacOS 10.15.4 Catalina?

Tags: c++, homebrew, macos-catalina, gcc-warning, gcc9

I wanted to start writing c++ code again and I just realized that the homebrew version of `gcc` does not compile any c++, c, or even fortran programs.

For example, I tried to compile the following simple hello_world.cpp program:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

using

```
g++-9 hello_world.cpp
```

The output I get is:

```
FATAL:/usr/local/Cellar/cctools/855/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!
```

I tried installing `gcc@8`, `gcc@7`, and compile but I still get the same message.

Moreover, the same error message is shown when I try to compile a `hello_world.c` program using `gcc-9` and a `hello_world.f90` program using `gfortran-9`.

The programs `*.c` and `*.cpp` compile fine with the `clang` and `clang++` compilers respectively. I also learned that `as` is an assembler, and that gcc can output a `*.s` file using the flag `gcc -S` but I still don't understand the error message.

I think I exhausted my c++ knowledge and internet search  before posting so thank you in advance!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542990/while-installing-on-osx-sierra-via-gcc-6-keep-having-fatal-opt-local-bin-l) answers your question?

Comment: Hi, no I saw that thread when I was searching for a solution earlier today but it doesn't help. I don't even know what MacPorts are and I don't have a port command on my machine.

Comment: It compiles and runs fine on my Mac. I would try `brew rm gcc` and also removing all your other unnecessary versions and then reinstalling with `brew install gcc` and try again.

Comment: I tried this as well (`brew rm gcc`) but the compiler won't work. Is there a way to delete all of brew and reinstall maybe? It seems like the problem is that assembler `as` which I never heard of before until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling all packages using

```
brew list | xargs brew reinstall
```

This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who has stumbled across this problem, you do not need to reinstall all of your `brew` packages. The troublemaker is `cctools`, which is no longer in the brew formulae list. If for some reason it is still hanging around on your system, you can either

```
mv /usr/local/Cellar/cctools{,-backup}
```

to make sure it is no longer seen by the `gcc` tool suite installed through `homebrew`, or you can outright remove it

```
brew uninstall cctools
```

I opted for the first, at the moment, because I am not sure what, if anything, removal would break. Once I have confirmed that there are no ill effects caused by not having this installed, I will remove it altogether from my system. That being said, I have confirmed that simply moving the directory takes care of the

```
FATAL:/usr/local/Cellar/cctools/855/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!
```

error being reported when you try and compile something with the GNU compiler on Mac OSX (in my case Catalina, but should be the same for Big Sur and Monterrey).